# How to merge elements of a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am dealing with binary numbers and I have a row matrix of 1 x 12.

```
A=[1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1]
```

I want to merge the 12 items in 3 groups so that they can be saved in an array.
For Example.

```
ARR[1]=1011
ARR[2]=0111
ARR[3]=1001
```

Is there any way to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: Is the output of the merging a string or a new binary number?

Comment: the output is a new binary number. Later on that number can be converted to a decimal equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked with Matlab for quite some time now but I think it goes something like this for what you want:

```
A=[1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1];
n = size(A) / 4;

for 1:n
    ARR(1:4,n) = A(n + (n-1)*4 : n*4);
end
```

Comment: That's not valid Matlab syntax

Comment: I don't have access to matlab at the moment and have thus not been able to test it. But syntaxwise it should be near to what is valid. The principle though should be what he is looking for

Comment: Actually I need a generic solution since the dimensions of the matrix may change

Comment: @Habib.Khan Do you allways want groups of 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can produce a matrix, where each row is a group:

```
A = [1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1];
B = reshape(A, [], 3).';
```

gives

```
B =
     1     0     1     1
     0     1     1     1
     1     0     0     1
```

---

If you really need the groups as a nested array you can convert to a cell array. But that's probably not needed, and is less efficient than having a numeric matrix:

```
B = reshape(A,[],3).';
B = mat2cell(B,ones(size(B,1),1));
```

gives

```
B{1} =
     1     0     1     1
B{2} =
     0     1     1     1
B{3} =
     1     0     0     1
```

Comment: Is there any way, how B{1} can be converted to equivalent decimal  numbers.

Comment: Is this what you want? `B = reshape(A, [], 3).'; bin2dec(char(B+'0'))`?

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab binary numbers are represented as strings.

https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/339967

So you can store the result as a 3x4 matrix of characters representing the binary numbers:

```
reshape(dec2bin(A), [4 3])'

ans =

1011
0111
1001
```

Or store them as numbers (and later convert them to binary strings when needed using `dec2bin`):

```
bin2dec(reshape(dec2bin(A), [4 3])')

ans =

11
 7
 9
```